# How can create simple PHP Search Engine Submission tool?

Tags: php, search-engine

How can create simple PHP Search Engine Submission tool, which allows that to submit the site URL to multiple search engines such as "http://www.google.com/addurl?q=www.yoursite.com&hl=&dqq=" and also "http://www.bing.com/webmaster/SubmitSitePage.aspx" or any other other search engines?

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562#44562)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to submit POST and GET requests to sites outside your server.